# Array manipulation php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need help for my program.
All I looking for is creating an array based on id_comment (id in mySQL table) then store it into another array

Example :
mySQL table

```
id | id_comment | weight
1  |     1      | 0.311925
2  |     1      | 1
3  |     1      | 0.122169
4  |     2      | 1
5  |     3      | 1
```

Expected array ouput :

```
array(
    [0]=>(0.311925, 1, 0.122169)
    [1]=>(1)
    [2]=>(1)
)
```

I've try to figure it out, but still can't make it work
Here's my code (the output is not as I expect):

```
$id = 5;

$arrayVector = array();

for ($i=1; $i <= $id; $i++) { 
    $a= mysqli_query($db, "SELECT weight FROM data_latih_model WHERE id_comment='$i'")or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($db));

    while ($b=mysqli_fetch_assoc($a)) {
        $arrayVector[] = array('key'=>$i,'value'=>$b['weight']);
    }
}

print_r($arrayVector);
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: I'd advise you to start using more helpfull vairables.  `$a` and `$b` are not particullary self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$arrayVector[] = array('key'=>$i,'value'=>$b['weight']);
```

To

```
$arrayVector[$i][] = $b['weight'];
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I overlooked that. Deleted that comment. Still though, it doesn't quite produce the correct output, as you'll have more arrays than the question asks for, as you will have as many entries as there are weights per comment, not just the amount of comments.

Comment: I'm making an assumption that the (1) represents an array of (1).  If Poster wants an actual (1), I would have to do a lot more fun.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the desired output, but I assumed the `0.311925, 1, 0.122169` and `1` was the entries of the weight, as a string. We'll see what OP respons with, hopefully we'll get some clarification :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL to fetch all the weights where the id is the same, and put that into a string separated by a given separator. Then, to reduce redundancy, instead of running the query inside a loop, run it once, with a `BETWEEN` clause.

```
$id = 5;
$vector = array();
$kelas = array();
$arrayVector = array();
$a = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id_comment, GROUP_CONCAT(`weight`, SEPARATOR ', ') as weight_grouped, kelas FROM data_latih_model WHERE id_comment BETWEEN 1 AND $i")or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($db));

while ($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a)) {
    $arrayVector[] = array($b['id_comment'] => $b['weight_grouped']);
    $kelas[] = $b['kelas'];
}
```

Comment: You could add an `explode()` to have the weights exploded in the actual values as an array

Comment: The OP requested the entry in the array to be `[0]=>(0.311925, 1, 0.122169)`, which is 1 entry with a string holding 3 values, separated by a comma. If you want three arrays, then using `GROUP_CONCAT()` is moot.

Comment: Could be, I read it as an array with the first entry once again being an array with 3 values.

Comment: If that's the case, the notation is a bit misleading, as arrays usually are noted with `Array` in front; as the parent array is in the question.